# CSS child height 100% with parent padding

Tags: html, css

I've gone through a lot of similarly named questions, but have not been able to find an answer.

When a parent div has a padding and I create a child div, width 100% follows the content-box size of the parent, but height 100% seems to take the border box value of the parent.
So for instance a parent with height 100px and 5px padding would create a child of height 100% with the height 100px instead of 90px.

Can anyone help me achieve the height of the parents content-box with padding?

I want to achieve a nice horizontal border, that is clipped in both ends, but is still centered.

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;`? Don't forget vendor prefixes.

Comment: You might wanna try using margin: 5px; for child element.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I found an issue and comes out the padding and border box were working just fine. Inside the child div was an ul, with a margin bigger than the parents padding and that pushed down the child div in the parent for some reason. Margin would also be a good idea, didn't think of it :)

Comment: With [content-box](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lwedkq0/1/) and [border-box](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lwedkq0/) - `height: 100%` respects `padding`

Comment: Give us the code

Comment: @ArtemSolovev asked 2 years, 8 months ago, I guess now he knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
   <div style:"padding:15mm">
        <div class="container" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; box-sizing: content-box;">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="images/image.png"
                alt="">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="images/image.png"
                alt="">
            <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="images/image.png"
                alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: The first div has a fixed size which is the black box.